# LEFT JOIN TABLE A AND TABLE B

Tags: sql-server, left-join

I have got 2 tables.

Table_A:

```
  Doc_No |  BUCKET  |DPD
  ---------------
  21     |M1        |11 
  22     |M1        |11
  23     |M1        |15
  24     |M1        |19
  25     |M1        |13
  26     |M1        |18
  27     |M1        |12
```

Table_B:

```
  BUCKET    |USER1
  -----------------
  M1        |David
  M1        |Tom
  M1        |Kirby
```

And I would like to get results as a table below 
 (DPD is ordered by a-z)

```
 Doc_No  |BUCKET    |DPD     |USER1
  --------------------------
 21      |M1        |11      |David
 22      |M1        |11      |Tom
 27      |M1        |12      |Kirby
 25      |M1        |13      |David
 23      |M1        |15      |Tom
 26      |M1        |18      |Kirby
 24      |M1        |19      |David
```

I don't know how to eliminate the redundant rows by using "normal" left join as below

```
    with a1 as
    (
        select *
            ,row_number() OVER (ORDER BY dpd) AS RowNum
        from TABLE_A
    )

SELECT * 
FROM a1 left join TABLE_B b on a1.BUCKET = b.BUCKET
```

I have used "Google" but I didn't have much luck finding any examples of this.

Any help would be appreciated. (Sorry about my English)

Comment: I don't understand the logic behind your expected output - why those 7 rows?

Comment: What @Cato is asking I think is why did David get assigned DPD 11 instead of 12, etc?

Comment: I think it's effectively a FIFO operation (see my answer), both, however, as the user table has nothing to order by, the order of insertion is lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't quite get the logic you want, as your table `Table_B` doesn't have anything to order by other than `User1`, thus the order of Kirby and Tom is reversed. You'll need to introduce another column to provide the ordering if the order has to be David, Tom, Kirby. (perhaps an `IDENTITY` or FIFO ID column)

Anyway, this should get you (most of the way) there:

```
USE Sandbox;
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.TableA (Bucket char(2), DPD tinyint);
CREATE TABLE dbo.TableB (Bucket char(2), User1 varchar(5));
INSERT INTO dbo.TableA (Bucket,
                        DPD)
VALUES ('M1',11), 
       ('M1',11),
       ('M1',15),
       ('M1',19),
       ('M1',13),
       ('M1',18),
       ('M1',12);

INSERT INTO dbo.TableB (Bucket,
                        User1)
VALUES ('M1','David'),
       ('M1','Tom'),
       ('M1','Kirby');
GO
WITH Sizes AS(
    SELECT Bucket, COUNT(*) AS Users
    FROM dbo.TableB
    GROUP BY Bucket),
FIFO AS (
    SELECT A.*,
           --ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A.Bucket ORDER BY DPD) AS RN, --Not actually needed
           ((ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A.Bucket ORDER BY DPD) -1) % S.Users)+1 AS UserRN
    FROM dbo.TableA A
         JOIN Sizes S ON A.Bucket = S.Bucket),
Users AS(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY B.Bucket ORDER BY B.User1) AS RN
    FROM dbo.TableB B)
SELECT F.Bucket, F.DPD, U.User1
FROM FIFO F
     JOIN Users U ON F.UserRN = U.RN;

GO

DROP TABLE dbo.TableA;
DROP TABLE dbo.TableB;
```

Comment: This is very helpful. Thank you so much.